# How can I trigger "UnsubscribeConfirmation" for SNS subscription?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sns

I've developed and successfully tested the "SubscriptionConfirmation" flow.
I'm now trying to debug the flow of "UnsubscribeConfirmation". As written in the [SNS documentation](https://docs.amazonaws.cn/en_us/sns/latest/dg/SendMessageToHttp.prepare.html):

> The UnsubscribeConfirmation message is used only when the
> subscription is deleted from the topic

When I'm deleting the subscription from the Topic I don't get any call to my endpoint with "UnsubscribeConfirmation" message type.
My question is: How can I trigger this?
Attached is a screenshot - I expect the event to be triggered after I clicked "Delete" button and got "Subscription deleted successfully." message.

I also wonder what is the importance of the process of unsubscribing. If the subscription is deleted anyway - what is there to verify?

[image]